# How to set a columnspan in tableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, merge, tablelayoutpanel, columnspan

I am using a `tableLayoutPanel` which consist of two rows. In first row I want two columns,
 and in second row I only need one column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

With the designer: put a control in the 2nd row and set its ColumnSpan property to 2.

In code:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var button = new Button();
        button.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
        tableLayoutPanel1.SetCellPosition(button, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 1));
        tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(button, 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are on visual studio, just set the **ColumnSpan** property of control you want to put in row 2 to '**2**' and it will take care of that.